# How do I create a Javascript package with a constructor in it?

Tags: javascript, constructor, package

Here I attempted to create a package called com.matogen.ght with a class in it, Calendar. I'd like the init() method to be called automatically when I instantiate the calendar object. The example below works, but I still have to explicitly call the init() method.

```
var com = {
    matogen : {
        ght : {
            'Calendar' : function() {       

                this.init = function() {
                    console.log("This is my constructor");
                }

            }
        }
    } 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var cal = new com.matogen.ght.Calendar();
    cal.init();

});
```

Comment: I haven' much experience in OOP with JavaScript, so any tips and suggestions on how to improve the code appreciated :)

Comment: btw, the quotes around 'Calendar' are not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just change your `init` function like so

```
this.init = (function() {
    console.log("This is my constructor");
}());
```

with a self executed anonymous function or, if you prefer, just call the function itself like so

```
...
    Calendar : function() {       

        this.init = function() {
            console.log("This is my constructor");
        };
        this.init();
    }
...
```

Comment: In your first example, this.init is assigned to undefined.  The function invokation is immediate, but the function does not call itself.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski, how does it work then? I always thought it calls itself (the above example does work - I'm asking why it works)... :/

Comment: It works, but won't you don't have, is an `init()` function that you can subsequently invoke from elsewhere because the result of the function is assigned to `this.init`, and the function returned nothing.  If you don't ever need to call `init()` ever again, then there's no point even having a handle to the function, or a function at all.  A function that calls *itself* would be recursive (i.e. calls itself from inside the function).  This is a function declaration that is immediately invoked by it's super context, not by its self.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as you are doing ***`new`***`com.matogen.ght.Calendar()`, `Calendar()` *is* your constructor.

So:

```
var com = {
    matogen : {
        ght : {
            Calendar : function() {       
                console.log("This is my constructor");
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

... would be accurate.

Comment: So, if I had another method *inside* Calendar, how would I call that, like say init()?

Comment: You can have functions within functions, you just call them as normal.  If you want to call them from outside the function, then you need to export its reference.  In the example in your question, you are exporting its reference by assigning an anonymous function to `this.init`.  `this` refers to the object you created by using `new` when you invoked your function.  That new object is assigned to your `cal` variable.